# [Using xsltproc]: output of running XSLT is missing xmlns attributes

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <exp:Export Version="3.0"
xmlns:L7p="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy"
xmlns:exp="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/export" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy">
<exp:References/>
<wsp:Policy xmlns:L7p="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy">
    <wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required">
        <L7p:AuditAssertion>
            <L7p:Level stringValue="INFO"/>
        </L7p:AuditAssertion>
        <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
            <L7p:Detail stringValue="2222"/>
        </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
        <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
            <L7p:Detail stringValue="333"/>
            <L7p:Level stringValue="WARNING"/>
        </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
        <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
            <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
                <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
                    <L7p:Detail stringValue="444"/>
                    <L7p:Level stringValue="FINE"/>
                </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
            </wsp:OneOrMore>
            <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
                <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
                    <L7p:Detail stringValue="555"/>
                    <L7p:Level stringValue="FINEST"/>
                </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
            </wsp:OneOrMore>
        </wsp:OneOrMore>
    </wsp:All>
</wsp:Policy>
</exp:Export>`
```

and I want to remove all of the

```
L7p:AuditDetailAssertion/L7p:Level
```

elements.

I am using the xsltproc from Redhat 7 to run the XSLT.

Here's the XSLT that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:L7p="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- TEMPLATE #1 -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- TEMPLATE #2 -->
  <xsl:template match="L7p:AuditDetailAssertion/L7p:Level" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output that I am getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<exp:Export xmlns:L7p="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy"   xmlns:exp="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/export" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy" Version="3.0">
  <exp:References/>
  <wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required">
      <L7p:AuditAssertion>
        <L7p:Level stringValue="INFO"/>
      </L7p:AuditAssertion>
      <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
        <L7p:Detail stringValue="2222"/>
      </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
      <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
        <L7p:Detail stringValue="333"/>
      </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
      <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
        <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
          <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
            <L7p:Detail stringValue="444"/>
          </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
        </wsp:OneOrMore>
        <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
          <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
            <L7p:Detail stringValue="555"/>
          </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
        </wsp:OneOrMore>
      </wsp:OneOrMore>
    </wsp:All>
  </wsp:Policy>
</exp:Export>
```

Notice that in the output, the wsp:Policy is missing the two "xmlns" attributes, "xmlns:L7p" and "xmlns:wsp".

How can I get the XSLT to include those "xmlns" attributes on the wsp:Policy element in the output XML?

Comment: Why do you consider those inner namespace declaration to be necessary? They are already present on the root element so the serializer of the XSLT processor is not duplicating them.

Comment: Hi Martin - The file is a policy in a gateway product, and the original XML above (including the inner namespace xmlns) was what was there.  I am trying to "tweak" the XML to eliminate those elements that I mentioned, and want to keep the structure of the tweaked XML as close to the original so that the gateway will be able to import the modified policy.  Thanks - Jim

Comment: Your input repeats the 2 namespace declarations on both `exp:Export` and `wsp:Policy`, which is entirely redundant. I don't think you will be able to get your processor to repeat this redundancy. At most, you may succeed at having them appear at `wsp:Policy` **instead of** at the root `exp:Export` element. But it really should not matter to you. If it does, then there is something wrong in your subsequent processing chain.